# Android Studio: Recognizing Resource Strings in AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

I imported one of my Android projects from Eclipse to Android Studio without any problem in building using Gradle. I just have a little annoying issue: String resources are not recognized correctly in the text editor indicating errors where ever there is a `@string/xxxx` . These errors are limited only to AndroidManifest.xml, not any other XML resource.

I can get also the same errors when Android Studio performs Code Analysis before version control commits.

I'd like to know how to tweak my project configs or gradle build script to fix this

Comment: Did you try this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18927972/my-debug-androidmanifest-xml-is-giving-me-cannot-resolve-symbol-errors

Comment: Fixed at first but Code Analysis still produces the same errors. When I navigate through Code Analysis results I get the same errors in the text editor again. The errors take the form of. 1) **Error: Cannot resolve directory '@string'** followed by **Error: Cannot resolve file 'string_name'**